# Tweet Rotator with jQuery json

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

Good Evening,

I'm using [this](https://gist.github.com/988557) script, it works really good but I want it to show all the tweets by a `User`, actually it shows all the tweet containing the `Keyword` you write.

```
$.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=any_keyword
```

Is there any good way to filter the results or any other way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to retrieve tweets from a particular user.

This seems to work for me:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=from%3A<USERID>
```

Just replace `<USERID>` with the login of the user you are looking for.